Why does the plot look different?
The below plot is given in this link:

I have written the following listing to match the above plot:
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters for liquid argon
polymer_chain_vec = []
N = 500  # Number of particles
sigma = 3.405  # Ångstroms
epsilon = 119.8  # K
temperature_float = 91.8  # Temperature in K
density_rho = 1.374  # Density in g/cm³
sim_steps_int = 100000
write_steps_int = 100

# Convert density to particles per unit volume (assuming density in g/cm³)
molar_mass_argon = 39.95  # g/mol
avogadro_number = 6.022e23  # particles/mol
density_particles = density_rho / molar_mass_argon * avogadro_number / 1e24  # particles per Å³

# Compute `periodic_boundary_int` from `density_rho`
def compute_box_size(N, density_particles):
    volume = N / density_particles
    return volume ** (1/3)

# Function to write to a text file
def write_txt(file_name_str, text_str):
    with open(file_name_str, 'a') as f:
        f.writelines(text_str)

# Convert polymer chain to a string
def polymer_to_str():
    str_str = ""
    for point_pt in polymer_chain_vec:
        str_str += f"({round(point_pt[0], 2)},{round(point_pt[1], 2)}) "
    return str_str

# Plot energies over simulation steps
def plot_energies(energies):
    plt.plot(range(len(energies)), energies)
    plt.ylabel('E')
    plt.xlabel('step')
    plt.show()

# Apply periodic boundary conditions
def apply_boundary_condition(point_pt):
    x, y = point_pt
    if x > periodic_boundary_int:
        x -= periodic_boundary_int
    elif x < 0:
        x += periodic_boundary_int

    if y > periodic_boundary_int:
        y -= periodic_boundary_int
    elif y < 0:
        y += periodic_boundary_int

    return [x, y]

# Compute Euclidean distance considering periodic boundary conditions
def get_distance(point_one_pt, point_two_pt):
    dx = point_one_pt[0] - point_two_pt[0]
    dy = point_one_pt[1] - point_two_pt[1]
    
    # Apply periodic boundary conditions
    if dx > periodic_boundary_int / 2:
        dx -= periodic_boundary_int
    elif dx < -periodic_boundary_int / 2:
        dx += periodic_boundary_int

    if dy > periodic_boundary_int / 2:
        dy -= periodic_boundary_int
    elif dy < -periodic_boundary_int / 2:
        dy += periodic_boundary_int

    return math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)

# Generate a random point within the simulation box and apply PBC
def get_random_point():
    x = random.uniform(0, periodic_boundary_int)
    y = random.uniform(0, periodic_boundary_int)
    return apply_boundary_condition([x, y])

# Lennard-Jones potential
def lj_energy_func(r_float):
    if r_float == 0:
        return float('inf')  # Avoid division by zero
    return 4 * epsilon * ((sigma / r_float) ** 12 - (sigma / r_float) ** 6)

# Calculate the potential energy of a bead
def get_potential(index_int):
    bead_potential_float = 0
    current_loc_pt = polymer_chain_vec[index_int]
    for i, other_loc_pt in enumerate(polymer_chain_vec):
        if i != index_int:
            r_float = get_distance(current_loc_pt, other_loc_pt)
            bead_potential_float += lj_energy_func(r_float)
    return bead_potential_float

# Calculate the total potential energy of the polymer chain
def get_total_potential():
    total_potential_float = 0
    for i in range(len(polymer_chain_vec) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(polymer_chain_vec)):
            r_float = get_distance(polymer_chain_vec[i], polymer_chain_vec[j])
            total_potential_float += lj_energy_func(r_float)
    return total_potential_float

# Initialize polymer chain with random points
def initialize_polymer():
    current_point_pt = get_random_point()  # Generate first point freely
    polymer_chain_vec.append(current_point_pt)
    for _ in range(N - 1):
        new_loc_pt = get_random_point()  # Generate subsequent points freely
        polymer_chain_vec.append(new_loc_pt)

# Run the Monte Carlo simulation
def run_simulation(steps_int):
    for _ in range(steps_int):
        rand_index_int = random.randint(0, len(polymer_chain_vec) - 1)
        before_loc_pt = polymer_chain_vec[rand_index_int]
        before_pot_float = get_potential(rand_index_int)
        new_loc_pt = get_random_point()  # Generate a new point freely within the box
        polymer_chain_vec[rand_index_int] = new_loc_pt
        after_pot_float = get_potential(rand_index_int)
        pot_diff_float = after_pot_float - before_pot_float

        # Metropolis criterion
        if pot_diff_float > 0:
            rand_float = random.random()
            if math.exp(-pot_diff_float / temperature_float) <= rand_float:
                polymer_chain_vec[rand_index_int] = before_loc_pt

# Calculate the radial distribution function (RDF)
def calculate_rdf():
    num_bins = 50
    max_distance = periodic_boundary_int / 2
    distances = []

    for i in range(len(polymer_chain_vec)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(polymer_chain_vec)):
            r = get_distance(polymer_chain_vec[i], polymer_chain_vec[j])
            distances.append(r)

    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(distances, bins=num_bins, range=(0, max_distance))
    bin_centers = 0.5 * (bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])

    # Calculate shell volumes
    bin_width = bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0]
    shell_volumes = 4 * np.pi * bin_centers**2 * bin_width
    
    # Normalize RDF
    particle_density = len(polymer_chain_vec) / (periodic_boundary_int ** 3)  # Density in particles per Å³
    rdf = hist / (shell_volumes * particle_density * len(polymer_chain_vec))

    return bin_centers, rdf


# Main simulation code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Compute the size of the simulation box based on the density
    periodic_boundary_int = compute_box_size(N, density_particles)

    # Initialize polymer chain
    initialize_polymer()

    # Run the simulation
    for step in range(1, sim_steps_int, write_steps_int):
        run_simulation(write_steps_int)

    # Calculate and plot RDF
    bin_centers, rdf = calculate_rdf()
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.plot(bin_centers, rdf, label='Simulated RDF', color='b')
    plt.xlabel('Distance (r) [Å]')
    plt.ylabel('g(r)')
    plt.title('Radial Distribution Function (RDF) for Liquid Argon at 91.8 K and 1.8 atm')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

The above listing generates the following plot:

This plot looks different than that of the reference plot.
Why is that?

What happens, if you use more simulation steps (sim_steps_int), a larger number of particles (N) and a larger number of bins (num_bins)? First I would try running more iteration steps, while keeping all other parameters fixed, as 100000 seems quite low for a Monte-Carlo simulation.

There is something wrong with your calculate_rdf() , but I can't tell what, exactly. I tried passing the resulting (x,y) coordinates of your simulation to rdfpy, a free package to calculate the rdf, and it gave expected results (0 for r < 1, a spike of height 1.7 at about r = 1.5, and a strongly damped sinusoid approaching 1 for large r). This was using only 32 particles and 10 times less simulation steps. I used dr=0.1 for rdfpy, for a total of 50 bins, instead of your 150.
